# MBProgressHUD produces many errors when compiling

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am working on iOS 4.2.

I have included MBProgressHUD h/m files into my iPhone project but when running I am getting so many errors as below in the MBProgressHUD m file.

See the image below for the errors I am getting.

[image: this is the errors]

Comment: I would suggest that you move to [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) which is beter maintained and updated.

Comment: Same here, we had a lot of problems with leaks with MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you included .m file without including the .h file, i just removed the .h file from my project and i recieved the same errors, make sure that the .h file is included in project as well